Issue with OutputCache invalidation by testId using Redis in .NET 8
I'm working on implementing OutputCache in .NET 8 and using Redis as the cache storage backend. My basic setup is as follows:
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
{
    options.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.Cache());
    options.AddPolicy("OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy", OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy.Instance); 
});
builder.AddRedisOutputCache("Redis");
.
.
.
app.UseOutputCache();

When applying caching to a controller like this:
[HttpGet]
[Route("test/{testId}")]
[OutputCache(Duration = 600)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(long testId)
{
    // Business logic here
}

The caching works fine and is stored in Redis with the following key structure:
__MSOCV_GETHTTPAPI-TEST.COM.AR/API/TEST/1Q*=
However, I'm facing issues invalidating the cache by testId. I'm trying to use the following to evict the cache:

await OutputCacheStore.EvictByTagAsync("__MSOCV_GETHTTPAPI-TEST.COM.AR/API/TEST/1");

But the cache entry is not being deleted. I'm not sure why this isn't working.
What would be the recommended approach to invalidate cache entries by testId? Is there a specific way to handle this with Redis and the OutputCache implementation in .NET 8? How can I ensure the cache is evicted properly?
Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Id wont get evicted since you the id as set as a key, not a tag.
